# How to define an appropriate complex type?

Tags: xsd

I have this in my xsd:

```
<xs:element name="Parameter" type="complex">
```

and I want to define complex like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="complex">
    1 xs:decimal
    2 xs:string
  </xs:simpleType>
```

So if the value for Parameter is decimal  to take decimal and if value is not decimal to assume that value is string. How to declare my complex type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `complexType` together with a [choice](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp) to express this:

```
<xs:complexType name="complex">
   <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="number" type="xs:decimal"/>
      <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Edit: Based on your comments maybe this is worth a try:

```
<xs:simpleType name="monat">
   <xs:union memberTypes="xs:decimal xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But JAXB will [translate](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_10-Defining-a-Type-Union.html) this to `String` anyway, so there's no benefit from the union, at least with respect to the generated classes. And that you are using JAXB is just a guess.

Comment: This could also be done with single element that accepts multiple types with `<xs:union>` but it wouldn't really separate strings and decimals because every valid decimal is also a string.

Comment: Will this firstly check for a decimal and then go to string?

Comment: @Dominating it will require you to wrap the content in an `number` or `string` element. As jasso pointed out, it's difficult otherwise because every number also is a string.

Comment: @Waldheinz my purpose is to generate class from this XSD and when class is generated i have two fields - number and string, but i want to have only one field and runtime to put data in it. According to the entered data - i want to choose between decimal and string.

Comment: @Waldheinz I use LinqToXsd.exe